# Check if an operator is defined for the object in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, generics

I want to create an extension for a list which would return an in iterable of cumulative values, my approach was like this:-

```dart
extension cumulativeList<T> on List<T> {
  Iterable<T> get cumulative {
    T? value;
    return Iterable<T>.generate(this.length, (i) {
      if (value == null) value = this[i];
      else value = value !+ this[i];  //gives and error that operator '+' is not defined for 'Object'
      return value;
    });
  }
}
```

So is there a way or a workaround to create a generic extension or function something like this, in which we could check if a certain operator is defined on the object?

Comment: `cumulativeList<T extends dynamic>` ? (not tested but this is how [Tween](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f9c825981c/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/tween.dart#L224) for example defines generic type)

Comment: of course if your type does not have `operator +` you will get runtime exception

Comment: @pskink yup, but this will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to extend T with dynamic, so my extension looks like this:-

```dart
extension cumulativeList<T extends dynamic> on List<T> {
  Iterable<T> get cumulative {
    T? value;
    return Iterable<T>.generate(this.length, (i) {
      if (value == null) value = this[i];
      else value = value + this[i];
      return value!;
    });
  }
}
```